# How to communicate atributes between classes

Tags: java, class

I have two classes, Window and Register, I catch a String in Window then i need to use in Register. Here is a piece of my code:

```
public class Window extends JFrame{
private String city;

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public Window() {
    Interface();
}

public void Interface(){

    botonContinuar = new JButton("Next");
    botonContinuar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //This get the value from my list...
            setCity((String) listaCity.getSelectedValue());

            Register open=new Register();

        }
    });
    botonContinuar.setBounds(164, 203, 89, 42);
    panel.add(botonContinuar);
```

}

public class Register extends Window{

```
public Register() {
    Window window=new Window();

    System.out.println(window.getCity());
```

}

> Output is :null:, when i was expecting the city catched from the list in Window. I'm new with Java, but I suppose the problem is that im creating a new Window objetc then all my atributes got initialized, but I cant figure out how to avoid this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should put your constructors on the top before any methods for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

When you will use this constructor, the city property will be initialized and you will see your output. Witoout it, the city remains `null`.

```
Window window=new Window("New York");

System.out.println(window.getCity());
```

Another option is to use `public void setCity(String city)` method, like:

```
Window window=new Window();
window.setCity("New York");
System.out.println(window.getCity());
```

Comment: The second option works, but It supposed i dont know which city the user is gonna select, then I can't just set `Name_City` , I would need a variable there, and thats where my problem is. The other guys suggest me to pass into the constructor, so i suppos is the only way :-/

Comment: It's your job to use the user input (city) or either get it from DB, I don't know what you are actually doing in your program

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- Unless and until you set city by default city variable would be null by default.
- You call set city only when you press button, which you never did.

If you need default value, i would suggest you initialize it like:

```
private String city = "defaultValue"; //or modify constructor to pass city value when object initializes.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems

1. You do not set the city attribute in Window's constructor.  As it stands Register would have to call Window's `actionPerformed` action for the city to be set.
2. In Window's Interface method a new Register is instantiated.  This might be a problem because if Register requires Window's Inteface method to be called, but Interface requires new Register to be called then this may lead to a StackOverflow exception or circular dependency.

Here are some suggestions:

1. Either Register calls `new Window()`, or Window calls `new Register()` but not both.
2. Consider passing the city to Register in the constructor.

Comment: I already did it, passing city as a parameter, like Register open=new Register(city);            but i thought maybe was another way to do this, because in the next frame i have to pass a lot of paramters...

Comment: Passing a lot of params between classes is a constant issue in programming.  My first programs used to pass a lot of data between classes and I would have to create Java beans to store all the data.  I was able to reduce a lot of the data that needed to be passed through refactoring and the use of a context that stores stateful data for a given application.

Comment: I see, ok then, i think i have no choice tho :-/